# Error trying copy a table into another without duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Basically, I want to copy table **DET** to table **DET_NEW**. I know that **DET** has some rows duplicated so I want to do it inserting duplicated rows just once. As you can see, I want to copy these rows by periods using **HDR** table.

Edit to add info: **DET** has no primary keys (that's why it has duplicated rows). **DET_NEW** has a composite primary key with **FK1** and **FK2**.

**PROBLEM:**

I know that this is not a new topic. I've tried all the solutions I've found and SQL Server returns an error about primery key constraint violation ("cannot insert duplicate key"). The queries were executed explicitly just with one core.

I saw that MySQL has INSERT IGNORE but I think there is nothing similar in SQL Server.

My solutions are the following ones:

Query 1:

```
INSERT INTO DET_NEW
    (FK1, FK2, value)
SELECT DISTINCT D.FK1, D.FK2, D.value
FROM HDR AS H,
    DET AS D
WHERE H.Date  >= CONVERT( datetime, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 20 )
    and H.Date < CONVERT( datetime, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 20 ) 
    and H.FK1 = D.FK1
```

Query 2:

```
INSERT INTO DET_NEW
    (FK1, FK2, value)
SELECT D.FK1, D.FK2, D.value
FROM 
(   SELECT DISTINCT D.FK1, D.FK2, D.value
    FROM HDR AS H,
        DET AS D
    WHERE H.Date  >= CONVERT( datetime, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 20 )
        and H.Date < CONVERT( datetime, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 20 ) 
        and H.FK1 = D.FK1
)D
```

Query 3:

```
INSERT INTO DET_NEW
    (FK1, FK2, value)
SELECT D.FK1, D.FK2, D.value
FROM HDR AS H,
        DET AS D
    WHERE H.Date  >= CONVERT( datetime, '2018-02-01 00:00:00', 20 )
        and H.Date < CONVERT( datetime, '2018-02-05 00:00:00', 20 ) 
        and H.FK1 = D.FK1
GROUP BY D.FK1, D.FK2
```

Query 4:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT D.FK1, D.FK2, D.value,
        row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY D.FK1, D.FK2, D.value ORDER BY D.FK1) AS [rn]
    FROM HDR AS H,
        DET AS D
    WHERE H.Date  >= CONVERT( datetime, '2018-02-01 00:00:00', 20 )
        and H.Date < CONVERT( datetime, '2018-02-03 00:00:00', 20 ) 
        and H.FK1 = D.FK1
)

INSERT INTO DET_NEW
    (FK1, FK2, value)
SELECT cte.FK1, cte.FK2, cte.value
FROM cte
WHERE cte.[rn] = 1
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I executed the following query: in the external part, the code checks if there is any duplication; on the inside, there is a SELECT DISTINCT, the same as Query 2. The results are more than 1k rows, so I've something incorrect in the queries.

```
SELECT D.FK1, D.FK2, COUNT(D.FK1) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT D.FK1, D.FK2, D.value
    FROM HDR AS H,
        DET AS D
    WHERE H.Date  >= CONVERT( datetime, '2018-02-01 00:00:00', 20 )
        and H.Date < CONVERT( datetime, '2018-02-03 00:00:00', 20 ) 
        and H.FK1 = D.FK1
    )D
GROUP BY D.FK1, D.FK2
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

The questions are: **Why I'm inserting duplicates? There is another efficient way for a large database (billions of rows)?**

Comment: What is the primary key on `DET_NEW`?

Comment: DET has no primary keys (that's why it has duplicated rows). DET_NEW has a composite primary key with FK1 and FK2.

Comment: It's likely that for some combinations of `FK1` and `FK2`, there is more than one different `value` in `DET`. You'll either need to include `value` in the composite key in `DET_NEW` or work out how you want to select which `value` to use for each key, e.g. using a `MIN` or `MAX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that for some combinations of `FK1` and `FK2`, there is more than one different `value` in `DET`. The following query should demonstrate that

```
SELECT FK1, FK2, MIN(value), MAX(value), COUNT(DISTINCT value)
FROM DET
GROUP BY FK1, FK2
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) > 1
```

You'll either need to include value in the composite key in `DET_NEW` or work out how you want to select which value to use for each key, e.g. using a `MIN` or `MAX`. The query that @MoinulIslam provided will also help you select a single value for each key. In that query it is just choosing the first one.

Comment: You're right. Some pais have different values. I only examined some of them but I didn't do it sistematically. This behaviour is very strange and absolutely contrary to the insertions logic. I have to check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO DET_NEW
    (FK1, FK2, value)   
SELECT  K.FK1, K.FK2, K.value
FROM
(SELECT D.FK1, D.FK2, D.value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.FK1, D.FK2 ORDER BY D.FK1, D.FK2) AS RN
FROM HDR AS H
    JOIN DET AS D ON H.FK1 = D.FK1
WHERE H.Date  >= CONVERT( datetime, '2015-01-01 00:00:00', 20 )
    and H.Date < CONVERT( datetime, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 20 )) K
    WHERE K.RN=1
```

Comment: Thanks! You're code is useful. It has a small mistake: you need the FROM statement before the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are chunking up the insert, the distinct is only acting on the "current chunk" and I suspect it it is therefore inserting a row with a value which already exists, hence the PK constraint violation. You really should provide detail in your question about what the composition of the primary key is, but I am assuming it is a composite of the 3 fields fk1, fk2 and value.

Perhaps rather than chunking by date, which presumably bears no relation to the values included in FK1, FK2 and value, you can order your "incoming" dataset by those fields, ensuring that all possible duplicates are held in your "incoming chunk", so that the distinct can work on it.

So I would take one of the fields, whatever will give you the best performance and use like this:

```
Create table #tt(
 fk1 fk1_datatype null
)

insert #tt(fk1)
select distinct fk1
from DET
order by fk1

<< while clause to get next value from #tt and read into @fk1>>

INSERT INTO DET_NEW
(FK1, FK2, value)
SELECT distinct FK1, FK2, value
FROM DET AS D
WHERE D.FK1 = @fk1

<< end of while clause removing @fk1 from #tt >>
```